# Writing to and Reading from the Clipboard in an afxwin application

Tags: visual-c++, clipboard, afx

I'm updating a large application in C++, which uses afxwin. I want to copy/paste information between instances of the application using the clipboard.  BUT in the afxwin header, the OpenClipboard function does not take any parameters, and does not seem to have a function for setting clipboard data.  The descriptions I have found all say if you don't send an HWND to OpenClipboard call, the SetClipboardData will fail. Well, that's exactly what's happening.

Is there a way for an afxwin app to write to the clipboard or are the two mutually exclusive?

If I create an external package to interface with the clipboard, will that get around this limitation?  Is there a valid reason for it?

I've searched Microsoft's user's guide (which is incredibly hard to follow) as well as stack overflow's information related to using the clipboard and other sites, too, which is why I think I may be up against something that can't be done.

Comment: Which OpenClipboard function that has no parameters are you looking at?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using standard Win32 calls in a MFC application, but there are also MFC specific versions of many of those calls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/clipboard-using-the-windows-clipboard?view=msvc-170

Comment: The no-parameters `OpenClipboard` [is a member function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#openclipboard) of `CWnd` class. The window handle comes from the `CWnd` instance on which it's called.  If you believe `SetClipboardData` fails because `OpenClipboard` was called without a valid window, that means you are calling it on an invalid `CWnd` instance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.